# How to properly structure viewmodel for related objects in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

Could someone advise me on “best practices” way to structure my ViewModel[s] for this UI ([see screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14397965/Job-In-Progress.png)) in knockout.
I am working on a UI for an website that sends faxes. User creates a Job and uploads documents into the Job.

The UI is responsible for  inserting data into db and pulling status information from db later in real time. 
Including screenshot of UI that I need to come up with using knockout.

User finds a Job by typing job name in “look up” text field. User Clicks “load” job. 
All documents related to the Job are loaded into the grid.
There are 3 boxes that display status count for each state of the document. “Pending”, “Faxed” and “Error”.
User clicks on status box and grid is reloaded with corresponding document records based on status.

This is what I get from API when I load a Job:

```
 {
  "job_id": 222,
  "job_name": "January renewals",
  "job_status": "new",
  "documents":[
            {"item_id": 12312312, "item_name": "Form_client_1","item_status": "pending"},
             {"item_id": 2343243, "item_name": "Form_client_2","item_status": "pending"},
             {"item_id": 45435, "item_name": "Form_client_3","item_status": "sent"},
             {"item_id": 9999, "item_name": "Form_client_4","item_status": "error"}
             ]
}
```

Please see the screenshot of UI - [UI screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14397965/Job-In-Progress.png)

**What would represent status boxes ? how would it all be glued together?**

Comment: There are only three types of 'objects' in Knockout - observable (object), observableArray (array of objects), or computed (special type of object)

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! Your question is really broad, and asking for opinions, which typically leads to a closed question. If you have a more practical question/problem be sure to ask though. In addition, [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) may be of use to you, but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the knockout site for example and opening up a jsbin and playing with it.

but just as  teaser I'd start out with something like

```
 function JobViewModel(){
  var self = this; 
  self.jobId = ko.observable(); 
  self.jobName = ko.observable(); 
  self.jobStatus= ko.observable()
  self.documents = ko.observableArray()
 }
 function DocumentViewModel() {
  var self = this; 
  self.itemId= ko.observable(); 
  self.itemName= ko.observable(); 
  self.itemStatus= ko.observable(); 
 }
 function ViewModel(){
  var self = this; 
  self.jobs = ko.observableArray(); 
 }

 ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

From all of this you can see the structure. You will need to add functions for populating the data.

Edit:

Use a [Computed Observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

```
 self.totals = ko.computed(function(){
       var total = 0; 
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.jobs(), function(job){
            total += job.documents().length; 
       });
 });
```

You would then bind those total's to this computed property.

I would also look into the [ko.utils.arrayFilter](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html). From there you can build a list of things with a specific status or really whatever you want.

Comment: Hi Matthew, Thanks for you answer. your example demonstrates the original model great and that is where I am as well. however i am looking to add "status" blocks functionality to this model and that is where my question is. I am not sure how to augment this model with additional pieces. Check out the screenshot and you will see what I mean....I want status counts to be links and on click filter the grid. So How to add it to the viewmodel?